# Notepad++ Replace hint for text file

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

i'm having some trouble about replacing option string. 
I need to replace

```
<option value="91">Afghanistan</option> need to become 
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
```

All between the two apix value need to be the state, the value after > and <
I can't figure how to do it with a reguar expression.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that new XML has a bad design, you have two identical values. Why would you need that? you can remove value="..." all together. :)

Comment: It's html form..if removing value , default behaviour is auto get the value from the content of option? :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for `"([^"]*)">([^]]*)<` and replace to `"\2">\1<`.

You need to select "regular expression" option.

[More explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kY9zI2/1).